# "Invalid context 0x0" when filling a UIBezlerPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

What to do?
I'm getting this error when I set the Backtracing Variable.

This Code is causing the error for sure:

```
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[ovalPath addArcWithCenter: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect)) radius: CGRectGetWidth(ovalRect) / 2 startAngle: 180 * M_PI/180 endAngle: 0 * M_PI/180 clockwise: YES];
[ovalPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect))];
[ovalPath closePath];

[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[ovalPath fill];
```

Error:

```
CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
  <<redacted>+48>
   <-[ViewController viewDidLoad]+2868>
    <<redacted>+996>
     <<redacted>+28>
      <<redacted>+76>
       <<redacted>+252>
        <<redacted>+48>
         <<redacted>+3456>
          <<redacted>+1684>
           <<redacted>+168>
            <<redacted>+36>
             <<redacted>+168>
              <<redacted>+56>
               <<redacted>+24>
                <<redacted>+540>
                 <<redacted>+724>
                  <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+384>
                   <<redacted>+460>
                    <UIApplicationMain+204>
                     <main+124>
Sep  5 21:55:56  Motion Tracking Radar - Aliem[2934] <Error>:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ovalPath fill]` can only be called if there is currently a global `CGContext` (i.e. calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` would return something other than `nil`). The most common way to get this is to run within `drawRect:`, but you can create temporary `CGContext` objects if you want, using generally using `CGBitmapContextCreate`, and make it the current context with `UIGraphicsPushContext`.

In most cases, when people encounter this problem, it's because they believe they can draw onto the screen at random points in the program. This is not true. You can only draw during the draw cycle, which is most often achieved by placing your code in a view's `drawRect:`. (There are other options using layers or the like, but this is the most common approach.)

See the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) (or the equivalent one on Mac), for an introduction to Cocoa drawing.